# write script which differs between mac and windows

Tags: windows, macos, shell-script

I'd like to write a script, which differ between mac and windows users,  something like this:

```
if (Mac)
 do this
if (Windows)
 do that
```

This shall be a script, which starts Cmake and builds the project for the corresponding IDE. All in all:

```
mkdir build
cd build
if (Mac)
  cmake .. -G "Xcode"
if (Windows)
  cmake .. -G "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013"
```

What is the command to differ between those two machines?

I know that for windows you usually have those .bat-files, but Mac can't handle them, can it? Which file-type do I need to use here then?

Comment: You could use `bash` scripts. You would need to install [cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) on windows ... a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill is there a possibility without installing anything.

Comment: Not as far as I know. They are completely different operating systems so there are no common default scripting languages. You have to install something on one or the other.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to write a single script, which works natively (no extra software needed) on *both* systems, which executes different commands based on which system it is being executed on.

Comment: Ok, so best thing would be to write a script for each OS. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Windows and Mac is unfortunately incompatible I wrote two files.

- `script_mac.command` for Mac
- `script_win.bat` for Windows

For Mac:
As I'd like to have an executable file (script runs, when double clicking) opened by terminal (Mac) I had to type in terminal `chmod +x script.command`. Furthermore, I'd to choose the default app being terminal for opening `script_mac.command` otherwise Xcode opened the code for `script_mac.command`.

That pretty much did the job for Mac and Windows.

Comment: then mark it as an answer. i think instead of .command .sh should've worked too - just needed to chmld it too - but maybe them you would not have to change default app.

Comment: I tried it with .sh-files, but it didn't work. Maybe I missed something. Have to wait 24h before accepting.

Comment: ah, ok - in my personal clock it was more than 24hrs already :D.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows there's cmd on Mac there's the (bash) shell.
They are incompatible - you could use python instead.
The bwst way is just to create a .bat/.cmd and a .sh file.